# Am I using ghcjs correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, haskell, ghcjs

I'm quite new to Haskell and ghcjs. I'm starting with the very first "Hello, world!" program to learn.

Here is my Haskell program, copied from GHCJS wiki:

```
module Main where
main = putStrLn "Hello world!"
```

I use the command `ghcjs -o hello hello.hs` to compile it to javascript, and I tried to run it on my Terminal with the command `node hello.jsexe/all.js`, but when I tried to open the generated file "index.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script language="javascript" src="rts.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" src="lib.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" src="out.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script language="javascript" src="runmain.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

But when I open this in Chrome the page is blank. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`putStrLn` outputs text to the Javascript console, which you can usually reach through the "developer tools" in your browser of choice. It does not generate any HTML.